# Multiple BitLocker Keys Recovery

Tags: bitlocker

I am new to this forum, i am looking for support on BitLocker Key Issue.

I have bit locker key issue on brand new laptop purchase 6 months back the screen went blank after spending several hours with HP, Microsoft and JL on phone trying all the recovery options. I have asked JL to recover my data and reset the laptop to factory.

JL has asked me to share the bitlocker key and I did so. To my surprise, the came back and asked me to share a second bit locker key as there are multiple partitions created on the laptop.

I have logged into the Microsoft account and all i could see for the devices that's mapped to my account shows only one bitlocker key.

Can someone help me, how to recover this i tried with HP and Microsoft and couldn't get any help related to this.

Thanks for your advise in advance.

Comment: I would assume it uses the same key on the same PC regardless of how many partitions, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Thank u, this is were i got really mad. I would wait for further comments from the forum